# Composing collection from subcollections

Tags: arrays, algorithm, collections

I have the following algorithmic problem.

**Input:** array A[1...n], integer m

I want to extract all possible subarrays with length in range [2...m] so that using these subarrays I can recreate the original array A. There are following constraints on subarrays:

1. Sum of lengths of subarrays should be equal to length of the
   original (that is n)
2. There shouldn't be same elements in two or more subarrays (this is
   basically retelling 1)

**Output:** the set of subarrays that form the original array A

For example we have A[1...4], m = 2
we have following subarrays with indices of the array A: (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (1,3) (1,4) (2,4)

The construction of array is possible with combinations (1,2) (3,4); (2,3) (1,4); (2,4) (1,3) etc.

The question is how to effectively implement the algorithm (using Java specifically if this of any use)?

Comment: Do you need the arrays themselves, or just the number?

Comment: I need the collection with subarrays of indices to construct A, like in the example.